# Convert PDF into Excel document using React JS?

Tags: reactjs, excel, pdf

I am new to react and I want to convert a PDF document (contains a table) into Excel document using REACT JS (basically I want to display the table from PDF on the page and to allow the user to download that table into excel). I tried to search on google but cannot find any tutorials or libraries of how to do it. Do any of you have an example of how to do it? or any tutorials that I can follow. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no libraries for client-side conversion between pdf and excel.
You can use npm libraries like [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert) to do that on the server side.

Comment: how is working? you upload the file and in the backend will convert the file to excel? I was thinking to use python to convert the file, upload the file (it will send the content to the API then convert it and send back to frontend) not sure if this will work.